# How is a file handle closed when it goes out of scope?

Tags: io, rust

I don't understand what Rust does with a file handle when it goes out of scope. For example, I create a file and write several words into it:

```
let wd = os::getcwd().unwrap_or(Path::new("/"));
let mut file = File::create(&Path::new("daemon_log.txt"));
file.write_all(format!("DAEMON CWD: {}", wd.as_str().unwrap_or("some problems")).as_bytes());
```

At the point where file goes out of scope, the compiler should insert instructions to free memory. If my understanding of how blocking IO is usually implemented is correct, then, apart from releasing memory, the process should also release some lock.

What I'm worried about is that in the source for `File`, I cannot find any tip for compiler to do it. [This old article](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/01/23/file-io-rust/) says that all the magic goes into implementation of the `Drop` trait for `File`, but it seems that it's not true for now, because I cannot find `Drop` trait implementation in either `std::ops.rs` nor in `std::old_io::fs.rs`.

**UPDATE**

I checked `File`s implementation of `write_all` again and found that the `write` method works with some descriptor (`FileDesc`). I haven't found any related info about it in docs, so went to GitHub and found [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sys/unix/fs.rs#L137). It looks like the answer to my question, but I am confused by one line in the comment:

> // closing stdio file handles makes no sense, so never do it

What does this mean? I should never invoke `libc::close` on my fd myself? Or they are themselves not sure how it should be implemented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For POSIX platforms, `File` is defined as `struct File(FileDesc)` in mod `sys::fs2`, where `FileDesc` is a wrapper around file descriptor number. The [destructor of `FileDesc`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sys/unix/fd.rs#L61) closes the file:

```
impl Drop for FileDesc {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // closing stdio file handles makes no sense, so never do it. Also, note
        // that errors are ignored when closing a file descriptor. The reason
        // for this is that if an error occurs we don't actually know if the
        // file descriptor was closed or not, and if we retried (for something
        // like EINTR), we might close another valid file descriptor (opened
        // after we closed ours.
        if self.fd > libc::STDERR_FILENO {
            let _ = unsafe { libc::close(self.fd) };
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation for Windows platform defines `File` as wrapper for `Handle` value, the destructor of which [calls `CloseHandle()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sys/windows/handle.rs#L40).

Comment: This seems like valid answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

See for example https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#L112 which specifies a "drop guard".

**Update** (to your update): The stdio handles are STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, which make no sense to close (except for daemonizing), so this is not done during normal IO operations.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand how it's related to File. But it pointed me to check Writer implementation again. I updated a question.